# 19.10 solaar not seeing logitech unifying receiver

Tags: logitech-unifying

lsusb shows it:

```
 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

I have a M325 mouse and a K360 keyboard that have become unreliable so I've set out to re-pair but solaar does not see the receiver.

I've tried two receivers in different ports on the machine.

After heynnema's comment:

```
 solaar/eoan,eoan,now 1.0.1
```

There are no logitech or solaar files in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and no reference to `logitech` in any of the files in the udev directory.

I have run `fwupdmgr -v update` without any notification.

```
fwupd is already the newest version (1.2.10-1ubuntu2)
```

And the service is running.

However when I run

```
sudo fwupdmgr get-updates


 Firmware metadata has not been updated for 30 days and may not be up to date.

 Update now? (Requires internet connection) [y|N]: y
 Fetching metadata https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz
 Downloading…             [***************************************]
 Fetching signature 
 https://cdn.fwupd.org/downloads/firmware.xml.gz.asc

 No releases found for device: Not compatible with bootloader version: failed predicate [BOT01.0[0-3]_* regex BOT01.04_B0016]




fwupdmgr get-devices
```

Has two logitech references:

```
Unifying Receiver
  DeviceId:             4588a84d1cfa1ddb273e9df28f6a44927e9b4e99
  Guid:                 9d131a0c-a606-580f-8eda-80587250b8d6
  Guid:                 279ed287-3607-549e-bacc-f873bb9838c4 <-         
EV_C52B
  Summary:              A miniaturised USB wireless receiver
  Plugin:               unifying
  Flags:                updatable|registered
  Vendor:               Logitech
  VendorId:             USB:0x046D
  Version:              RQR12.09_B0030
  VersionBootloader:    BOT01.04_B0016
  VersionFormat:        plain
  Icon:                 preferences-desktop-keyboard
  InstallDuration:      7
  Created:              2020-01-04
```

Comment: Look in `/etc/udev/rules.d` and see if you find `42-logitech-unify-permissions.rules`, or something similar. What version solaar do you have? Have you done the receiver firmware update?

Comment: @heynnema I've added info to the question. Thanks

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 7):

**1. Install the latest solaar**

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:solaar-unifying/stable`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install solaar` # if Gnome then also install `solaar-gnome3` (not required with recent versions of Solaar).

**2. Check for udev rule**

Check `/etc/udev/rules.d` for a file, called either `42-logitech-unify-permissions.rules` or `60-solaar.rules`.

**3. Update the receiver firmware**

https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360033207154-Logitech-Unifying-Receiver-Update

https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035037273

**Note**: The `Ubuntu Software` app should be able to update the firmware also.

**4. Check for plugdev group**

`groups`

Make sure you're in the `plugdev` group

**Note**: log out/log in required if you added yourself to this group.

**5. Replug**

Unplug, and reinsert the receiver dongle.

---

**Note**: for debugging purposes, you can use the `solaar show` or `solaar -d` commands.

**Note**: see https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar for more info

**Note**: see https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/tree/master/rules.d for udev rule installation

**Note**: see https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/installation for manual install instructions that might help debug

Comment: All checked and installed. NOTE: I am running MATE. Installing solaar-gnome3 will overwrite the MATE desktop settings and set up for gnome3 desktop. Not at all what I want. Been there/ Done that/ Won't ever do it again. Note that I found no logitech or solaar in /udev

Comment: @StephenBoston You might articulate your MATE environment in your question. Also, do you have a nano receiver, or a unifying receiver? In your BIOS, is USB set to legacy?

Comment: @StephenBoston  See https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/tree/master/rules.d for udev rule.

Comment: @StephenBoston see https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/installation for manual install instructions that might help you debug

Comment: @StephenBoston status please...

Comment: - I have a new Logitech mouse and old keyboard, Solaar sees only the old receiver, and I can connect mouse only to the new receiver. The effect is that I have to waste 2 usb sockets
- After installing the above Solaar from ppa:solaar-unifying/stable, it freezes on Ubuntu 20 (complains about missing udev fs)

Comment: @iirekm What version Solaar? Did you check #2 and #3 in my answer? Is the new USB dongle a unifying type (has orange symbol on it)?